# DjangoRestFramework serializer filter and limit related

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, serialization, related-content

Thats my models:

```
class Org:
    name = CharField()
    owner = ForeignKey(User)

class Cafe:
    name = CharField()
    org = ForeignKey(Org)

 class Product:
    name = CharField()

 class Assortment:
    cafe = ForeignKey(Cafe)
    product = ForeignKey(Product)
    price = IntegerField
```

So the deal is - i need to search products with very specific way.
It should looks like this:
/assortment/search/?searh=cola

```
'cafe':{
    'id:1,
    'name': 'Foo',
    'assortment': [
        {
           'product': {
               'id': 1,
               'name': 'Cola'
           },
           'price': 100
        },
        {
           'product': {
               'id': 2,
               'name': 'Coca-cola'
            },
            'price': 200,
        }
    ],
    'search_count': 5,
},
'cafe': {
    'id':2,
    'name': 'Bar',
    'assortment': [
        {
            'product': {
                 'id': 3,
                 'name': 'Sprite-cola',
             },
             'price': 150,
        },
    ] 
    'search_count': 1,
}
```

So the problem is - when i search like

```
Cafe.objects.filter(assortment__product__name='cola')
```

It works, it shows all Cafes where product with name 'cola' exists, but problem is  DJF serializer

```
class CafeSerialzier:
     assortments = AssortmentSerializer(source='assortment_set')
     search_count = IntegerField(source='assortment_set.count')
```

assortments and search_count shows all assortment and count of it, and does not consider search arguments, which is expected. So the question is - how to pass search parameters into source='assortment_set' (Also i need to limit results to 3) and how to count all search results.
I've tried SerializerMethodField for assrotments, it solves a part of my problems but it causes a lot of queries.
Overriding of `get_field` method has the same problems.
So is there sane way to filter and limit queryset related field in ModelSerializer and get count of unlimited but filtered queryset of the same field?

Comment: Can you provide also the view where you are doing the filtering?

Comment: Sure, view `class CafeAssortmentSearch(generics.ListAPIView): search_fields = ('assortment__product__name', 'assortment__product__category__name')`

Comment: and serializer: `class CafeAssortmentSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Search serializer for Assortment model."""

    assortment_count = serializers.IntegerField(source='assortment_set.count')
    assortments = AssortmentListSerializer(source='assortment_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""

        model = models.Institution
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'assortments', 'assortment_count')`

Comment: sorry about formatting

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get assortment resource via: `/assortment/search/?search=cola` so your response should not contain cafe resources, but assortment resources like this:

```
[
    {
       'product': {
           'id': 1,
           'name': 'Cola'
       },
       'price': 100,
       'cafe': 1 # id of the cafe or any extra information
    },
    {
       'product': {
           'id': 2,
           'name': 'Coca-cola'
        },
        'price': 200,
        'cafe': 1 # id of the cafe or any extra information
    }
]
```

You should create a `ListView` for `Assortment` model with an `AssortmentSerializer`. Instead of using `Cafe.objects.filter(assortment__product__name='cola')` you will use `Assortment.objects.filter(product__name='cola')` in your search view (list view).

Comment: I know, but the problem is I need to group search results ( assortments ) by 3 and by caffee

Comment: You can group the result in the view by coffe id and assortment number before returning the result (implement your own list method), but the output that you want is not Restfull.